# How does Python split() function works

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

```
def loadTest(filename): 
    f=open(filename,'r')
    k=0
    line=f.readline()
    labels=[]
    vectors=[]
    while line and k<4:
        k=k+1
        l=line[:-1].split(r'","')
        s=float(l[0][1:])
        tweet=l[5][:-1]
        print(l)
        line=f.readline()
     f.close()
     return
```

What do `split(r'","')` actually does inside python split method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l

Comment: The docs can. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Raw string vs Python string

#### **`r'","'`**

The **r** is to **indicate** it's a **raw string**.

How is a raw string different to a regular python string?

The **special characters lose** their **special meaning inside** a **raw string**. For example `\n` is a newline character inside a python string which will lose its meaning in a raw string and will simply mean backslash followed by n.

## `string.split()`

`string.split()` will break and split the `string` on the argument that is passed and return all the parts in a list. The list will not include the splitting character(s).

**`string.split('","')`** will break and split the string on every `","` and return all the broken parts in a list excluding `","`

Eg:

```
print 'Hello world","there you are'.split(r'","')
```

Output:

```
['Hello world', 'there you are']
```

---

---

---

## `split()` can do even more...

You can specify how many parts you want your string to break into by passing in an extra parameter.

Lets consider this string: `'hello,world,there,you,are'`

1. Split on all commas and break into n+1 parts where n is the number of commas:

```py
>>>print 'hello,world,there,you,are'.split(',')
['hello', 'world', 'there', 'you', 'are']
```

2. Split on first comma and break only into 2 parts.

```py
>>>'hello,world,there,you,are'.split(',',1)  
['hello', 'world,there,you,are']
```

3. Split on first and second comma and break into 3 parts. And so on...

```py
>>>'hello,world,there,you,are'.split(',',2)
['hello', 'world', 'there,you,are']
```

---

## And even more...

From the docs:

> If splitting character(s) i.e separator is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

For example,

```
>>>' 1  2   3  '.split()
['1', '2', '3']

>>>'  1  2   3  '.split(None, 1)
['1', '2   3  ']

>>>''.split()
[]

>>>'    '.split()
[]


>>>'      '.split(None)
[]
```

---

## And even...

.

.

.

## What?

Isn't it enough that you are looking for more? Don't be so greedy :P.
Just question yourself`?`, it will make you non-greedy :D (You will get the joke if you know regular expressions)

Answer (score 1):

It splits the string into items of a list.
For example

```
'I am a string'.split(' ')
```

Gives the output

```
['I', 'am', 'a', 'string']
```

Explanation:
Here, I used `' '` as a split so every time a `' '` character comes, it splits the string into a new item of list.